# AWS Certificate Manager - DNS validation on Hostinger failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, aws-certificate-manager, aws-acm

I'm trying to validate my Hostinger DNS on AWS Certificate Manager.

I tried using e-mail validation method

[image]

And it still failed

[image]

Also, using validation by adding CNAME and value in my DNS Record like this

[image]

And confirming using `nslookup`

[image]

And instantly gave failed

[image]

I searched for some solutions like [this one](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/acm/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-email-validation.html) and nothing helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is same case of another question, you may try to add a CAA record, like:

```
nome    Conteúdo                  prio
@       0 issue "amazon.com"      0
@       0 issuewild "amazon.com"  0
```

See the docs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/setup-caa.html